# C output not printing overflow

Tags: c

I would like to understand why the output show overflow for unsigned short but not for unsigned long? Here is an example?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned short us(float s);
unsigned long ul(float l);
float a = -10;
int main()
{
    printf("us method return: %d ", us(a));
    printf("\nul method return: %d ", ul(a));
    return 0;
}

unsigned short us(float s)
{
    return (s + 1);
}
unsigned long ul(float l)
{
    return (l + 1);
}
```

And the output is:

```
us method return: 65527 
ul method return: -9
```

Comment: Works if you use correct print specifiers: https://ideone.com/STzIMN

Comment: Use `%u` for unsigned int and `%lu` for unsinged long. Here is some formatting: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm

Comment: Use `"%hu"` as with `printf("us method return: %hu\n", us(a));`

Answer (score 2):

`%d` expects the argument to be of type `int`.

`printf()` being a variadic function, the integer promotions are performed on each argument.

Once you provide a `unsigned short`, it can be promoted to `int`, but `unsigned long` (being in higher rank than `int` ) cannot be *promoted* to `int`, hence you end up supplying wrong type of argument to `%d` which will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should use `%lu` to print an `unsigned long` value.

Comment: thanks for the valuable info. But, why would it not print out max int (in term of %d) to show overflow for the unsigned long case and that it can only print max int?